# how do i call a subclass method on a superclass list containing subclasses

Tags: c#, class, methods, subclass

I had a hard time wording my title so let me try to elaborate now. First here is my relevant code :

```
class Question
    {
        static bool checkFile(XElement q)
        {
            foreach (XElement a in q.Descendants())
            {
                if (a.Name.LocalName == "file")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected string questionText;
        protected List<File> files;
        protected Question question;
        public Question(XElement q)
        {
            questionText = q.Element("questiontext").Element("text").Value.ToString();
            string name = q.Attribute("type").Value.ToString();
            if (checkFile(q))
                files.Add(new File(q));
        }
    }
    class multichoice : Question
    {
        private List<string> answers;
        public multichoice(XElement q)
            : base(q)
        {
            foreach (XElement a in q.Elements())
            {
                if (a.Name.LocalName == "answer")
                    answers.Add(a.Element("text").Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        public void writeQuestion(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag("p");
            writer.Write("<strong>Multiple Choice: </strong>" + this.questionText);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.AddAttribute("type", "A");
            writer.RenderBeginTag("ol");
            foreach (string answer in answers)
            {
                writer.RenderBeginTag("li");
                writer.Write(answer);
                writer.RenderEndTag();
            }
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
    }
    class truefalse : Question
    {
        public truefalse(XElement q)
            : base(q)
        {

        }
        public void writeQuestion(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.RenderBeginTag("strong");
            writer.Write("True or False : ");
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.Write(questionText);
        }
    }
```

So I am creating multiple types of questions all being subclasses of "Question". Question contains all data that applies to every type of question and these subclasses contain methods unique to them, the main one being "writeQuestion".
Now what I am trying to do with it is something like this:

```
static List<Question> collectQuestions(XDocument doc)
    {
        XDocument xdoc = doc;
        string elementName = null;
        List<Question> questions = null;
        foreach (XElement q in xdoc.Descendants("question"))
        {
            elementName = q.Attribute("type").Value.ToString();
            if (elementName != "category")
                continue;
            if (elementName == "truefalse")
                questions.Add(new truefalse(q)); //writeTrueFalse(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "calculatedmulti")
                questions.Add(new calculatedmulti(q)); // writeCalculatedMulti(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "calculatedsimple")
                questions.Add(new calculatedsimple(q)); // writeCalculatedSimple(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "ddwtos")
                questions.Add(new Draganddrop(q)); //writeDragAndDrop(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "description")
                questions.Add(new Description(q)); // writeDescription(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "essay")
                questions.Add(new Essay(q)); // writeEssay(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "gapselect")
                questions.Add(new Gapselect(q)); // writeGapSelect(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "matching")
                questions.Add(new Matching(q)); // writeMatching(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "multichoice")
                questions.Add(new multichoice(q)); // writeMultipleChoice(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "multichoiceset")
                questions.Add(new Allornothing(q)); // writeAllOrNothing(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "numerical")
                questions.Add(new Numerical(q)); // writeNumerical(writer, q);
            else if (elementName == "shortanswer")
                questions.Add(new shortanswer(q)); // writeShortAnswer(writer, q);
            else
                continue;
        }
        return questions;
    }
questions = collectQuestions(someDocument);
foreach (Question question in questions)
            {
                question.writeQuestion(writer);
            }
```

Is there a way to call the writeQuestion on each of the items? right now it of course gives the error that Questions does not contain a definition for writeQuestion even though each of its subclasses does. Please comment if i should add anything more for clarification, my code has gotten a little mangled as i have been repeatedly reworking it. I am decently new to working with classes like this so i may be missing some key concepts, please point out anything you see, thankyou.

Comment: Why isn't there a `writeQuestion` method in the Question superclass? Either add one in or make an interface for this.

Comment: BTW even when Eric Lippert is right about how to solve your issue, I see a not clear separation of concerns: you're coupling your classes with how they're represented as HTML. This is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Matias Fidemraizer, What my full code is doing is parsing an xml file and reformatting it into the needed format in an html file. i am storing the data i need within these questions as well as the block of code that each question is represented by. I am then outputting these blocks to file. So far it is working well. What is it that makes this a bad idea and what would you suggest instead?

Comment: I'm preparing an answer to explain you how I would organize your code better, hold some minutes and you'll be able to check it!

Comment: I've published it, let me know what do you think ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the base class `abstract`, add an abstract `WriteQuestion` member to the base class, and then `override` it in each concrete implementation.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, Thankyou for your help, I marked the superclass as abstract and created an abstract writequestion method in the superclass, now when i create an override writequestion in the subclasses it says no suitable method found to override. Could you perhaps add an example of how it might work in my code?

Comment: Did you make the method to override virtual?

Comment: Okay i got that part working, Thank you for your help! On to the error that fixing this caused of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I would split out your code into more classes to get a good separation of concerns.

Your `Question` class and specializations (i.e. derived classes) shouldn't know about how they're stored and also they shouldn't know about how they're turned into some format like an HTML representation.

I would define a class called `XmlQuestionConverter`:

```
public class XmlQuestionConverter
{   
    public XmlQuestionConverter() 
    {
        TypeToConvertMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Question, XElement>>
        {
            { typeof(TrueFalseQuestion), new Action<Question, XElement>(ConvertTrueFalseFromXml) }
            // other mappings...
        };
    }
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<Question, HtmlTextWriter>> TypeToConvertMap
    {
        get;
    }

     // This dictionary maps element names to their type
     private Dictionary<string, Type> QuestionTypeMap { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
     {
          { "truefalse", typeof(TrueFalseQuestion) },
          { "multichoice", typeof(MultiChoiceQuestion) }
          // And so on
     };

     public IList<Question> ConvertFromXml(XDocument questionsDocument)
     {
        // This will get all question elements and it'll project them
        // into concrete Question instances upcasted to Question base
        // class
        List<Question> questions = questionsDocument
                     .Descendants("question")
                     .Select
                     (
                        element =>
                        {
                           Type questionType = QuestionTypeMap[q.Attribute("type").Value];
                           Question question = (Question)Activator.CreateInstance(questionType);

                           // Calls the appropiate delegate to perform specific
                           // actions against the instantiated question
                           TypeToConvertMap[questionType](question, element);

                           return question;
                        }
                     ).ToList();

        return questions;
     }

     private void ConvertTrueFalseFromXml(TrueFalseQuestion question, XElement element)
     {
          // Here you can populate specific attributes from the XElement
          // to the whole typed question instance!
     }
}
```

Now you can convert an `XDocument` to a question list, and we're ready to turn them into HTML with an `HtmlTextWriter`:

```
public class HtmlQuestionConverter
{
    public HtmlQuestionConverter() 
    {
        TypeToConvertMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<Question, HtmlTextWriter>>
        {
            { typeof(TrueFalseQuestion), new Action<Question, HtmlTextWriter>(ConvertTrueFalseToHtml) }
            // other mappings...
        };
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, Action<Question, HtmlTextWriter>> TypeToConvertMap
    {
        get;
    }

    public void ConvertToHtml(IEnumerable<Question> questions, HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        foreach (Question question in questions)
        {
            // Calls the appropiate method to turn the question
            // into HTML using found delegate!
            TypeToConvertMap[question.GetType()](question, htmlWriter);
        }
    }

    private void ConvertTrueFalseToHtml(Question question, HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        // Code to write the question to the HtmlTextWriter...
    }
}
```

Going this way I don't see that you need polymorphism at all:

```
XmlQuestionConverter xmlQuestionConverter = new XmlQuestionConverter();
IList<Question> questions = xmlQuestionConverter.ConvertFromXml(xdoc);

HtmlQuestionConverter htmlQuestionConverter = new HtmlQuestionConverter();
htmlQuestionConverter.ConvertToHtml(questions, htmlWriter);
```

**Note: I couldn't try to execute this code and I'm not 100% sure if it'll work, but it's a good start to understand how to implement your code with a clear separation of concerns! You might need to do some tweaks to adapt my code to your actual use case.**

Comment: Wow, i really appreciate the effort you put into this. It definitely looks better than what i have. After i work out all the other kinks i have in my program i will see how i can transition my template into a format similar to this. Once again i appreciate the teaching.

Comment: @Zannith You're welcome! Tomorrow I'll tweak to even define element converters like `TrueFalseQuestionConverter` instead of using delegates.

Comment: @Zannith BTW I've some idea... do you really need to use XML? JSON serialization is very very easy to use with JSON.NET. You could extremely simplify your code using JSON instead of XML. Text question to objects would be done automatically, you would throw away the `XmlQuestionConverter`.

Comment: Yes, i'm creating this program as a local use plugin for moodle rooms. to take their online quiz formats into something printable. their export format is in this xml

Comment: @Zannith You can still implement XML serialization, you would be able to store your object model into XML and back to objects easily without custom work (or less than current one)

Comment: Thank you for the JSON suggestion, I have gotten around to looking into it and i do believe it could be helpful in minimizing my custom work.

Comment: @Zannith No problem! ;)